# Lat/Lng value Store in firebase separately assign to variable

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

[This is my firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpcsf.png) using Split method i try to separate `lat/lan` value stored in Firebase, but only first value show but second value cannot get.error occured and stop run.String lat=gpsVal[0] can assign but String lang=gpsVal[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpcsf.png) cannot assign.app close.
but when i add manual value lat/lng: (7.714195099999999,81.6947587)" to example variable then can assign both value(String lat=gpsVal[0],lang=gpsVal[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpcsf.png)) to variable

This my code:

```
final ArrayList <String> locationnew = new ArrayList <String>();
    database.orderByChild("ItemName").equalTo(name).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                    for(DataSnapshot suggestionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                         itcat=suggestionSnapshot.getKey();
                         String loc=suggestionSnapshot.child("ShopLocation").getValue().toString();
                         names1.add(itcat);
                         locationnew.add(loc);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AWW SNAP... Something is Wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        String[] loca=new String[1000];

        for(int i=0; i < locationnew.size(); i++)
        {
            loca[i]=locationnew.get(i);
        }

        String find_lat_lan = "";
        serch2.setText(String.valueOf(loca[0]));
        String example = serch2.getText().toString();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(example);
        while(m.find()) {
            find_lat_lan = m.group(1) ;
        }

        String[] gpsVal = find_lat_lan.split(",");
        String lat=gpsVal[0];
        String lang=gpsVal[1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to use the `locationnew` list outside the `onDataChange()` which will always be `empty` due the asynchronous behaviour of this method.

With other words, you cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. You cannot simply use that result outside the `onDataChange()` method because by the time you are trying to use that `list` outside the method, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible. A quick solve for this problem would be to move all your logic only inside the `onDataChange()` method like this:

```
    final ArrayList <String> locationnew = new ArrayList <String>();
    database.orderByChild("ItemName").equalTo(name).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            for(DataSnapshot suggestionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                itcat=suggestionSnapshot.getKey();
                String loc=suggestionSnapshot.child("ShopLocation").getValue().toString();
                names1.add(itcat);
                locationnew.add(loc);

            }
            String[] loca=new String[1000];

            for(int i=0; i < locationnew.size(); i++)
            {
                loca[i]=locationnew.get(i);
            }

            String find_lat_lan = "";
            serch2.setText(String.valueOf(loca[0]));
            String example = serch2.getText().toString();
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(example);
            while(m.find()) {
                find_lat_lan = m.group(1) ;
            }

            String[] gpsVal = find_lat_lan.split(",");
            String lat=gpsVal[0];
            String lang=gpsVal[1];
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AWW SNAP... Something is Wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Or if you want to use it outside the method, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex Mamo. you sold my problem.i tried lot of hours to solve it. and thanks your advice

Answer (score 1):

add it seperatly

```
 private void subscribeToUpdates() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(getString(R.string.firebase_path));

    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarker(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            setMarker(dataSnapshot);
            Log.d("markerKey", "hello: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
//                subscribeUpdates(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}

private void setMarker(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // When a location update is received, put or update
    // its value in mMarkers, which contains all the markers
    // for locations received, so that we can build the
    // boundaries required to show them all on the map at once
    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
// not important
    newName = key.replace(" ", ".");
    HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
        mMarkers.put(key, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(newName).position(location)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(colours[new Random().nextInt(colours.length)]))));
    } else {
        mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);
    }

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker marker : mMarkers.values()) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 300));
}
```

and receive it like this on map

Comment: using google api auto complete method  i add location to database.in my code if i print (find_lat_lan) it show 7.714195099999999,81.6947587 but error occurred separate this from comma

Comment: find_lat_lan = m.group(1) ;
giving you string ??? without error ? because if this is null of course you will get error